# Find scalars $a_i$ not all $0$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n^2}a_i\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}^i =0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find scalars $a_i$ not all $0$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n^2}a_i\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}^i =0$

I know $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}^i$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ when $i=0$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}^i$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2^i & i \cdot 2^{i+1}\\0 & 2^i\end{bmatrix}$ when $i>0$

Comment: $Mat_{n,n}(F)$ does not have dimension n...

Comment: How can I show the scalars exists ?

Comment: Hint: Use Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Comment: For the record: note that $$\pmatrix{2&4\\0&2}^i = \pmatrix{2&i\cdot 2^{i+1}\\0&2^i}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wrong about $\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^{i}$, try $i=2,3,...$ Anyway, do you know about [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) ? A consequence of this theorem is that the characteristic polynomial $P$ of $A$ satisfies $P(A)=0$ (where $\displaystyle A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$). Here, $P(X)=(X-2)^{2} = X^{2} - 4X + 4$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've never heard of this theorem, but it seems easy to understand the proof.